# How can I run this command in command prompt from a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Change the directory e.g. `cd "Documents"`

then run the following:

```
ssh -i "miftah01.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-91-88-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Whenever I try to do this, the .bat file only executes the directory change. I have *cygwin.exe* so that ssh string does work.

Comment: So when you execute these commands from a command prompt does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain this is the answer.

You launch ssh from the cygwin prompt ($) rather than directly from the cmd prompt. I use batch files of the following form

```
PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%
cd %HOME%\"Documents"
ssh -i "miftah01.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-91-88-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

The command that makes it work is `PATH=...`; but if you're then going to run these from shortcuts the `cd` command needs to resolve the path better.